# Need help on compare and merge two array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have following two arrays which comes from the same database use the same query to get both. both contains information about a single sales order having two different line items(Bill of materials) the first one has Line Item`ItemID= 600271` and the second one has LineItem `ItemID=600274` but as you can see below they both have the same Sales Order Number `[CustomerSONo] => [7] => **15020**`.

**Difficulties i am having**: tried  to use  `Built in functions` but i have a hard time creating a loop to compare and merge the two then store the difference in separate variable.

so How can i compare or union these two array's. ?

//I want to end up like this

```
  Customer ID     Customer_Bill_Name.......        Item ID 1            Item ID 2           
    XXX001           XXX Company Name......           WH15 02             600278
```

//query

```
    $result= --select statement--;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        print_r($row);
     }
```

//Array 1

```
     Array ( 
           [0] => XXX001 
           [CustomerId] => XXX001 
           [1] => XXX Company Name.*
           [Customer_Bill_Name] => XXX Company Name.* 
           [2] => DHE 
           [WhichShipVia] => DHE [3] => 
           [INV_POSOOrderNumber] => [4] => 2014-12-19 
           [ShipByDate] => 2014-12-19 [5] => 
           [GoodThruDate] => [6] => 
           [CustomerSONo] => [7] => 15020 
           [Reference] => 15020 [8] => 2014-11-25 
           [TransactionDate] => 2014-11-25 [9] => 1 
           [DistNumber] => 1 
           [10] => 70.0000000000000000000 //here is the difference 1
           [Quantity] => 70.0000000000000000000  //here is the difference 2
           [11] => 600271  //here is the difference 3
           [ItemId] => 600271 //here is the difference 4
           [12] => ASSY7.60-15SL/8 FRM I1 15X6 6-6, BLK (GWT-761508 (24) //here is the difference 5
           [SalesDescription] => ASSY7.60-15SL/8 FRM I1 15X6 6-6, BLK (GWT-761508)(24)//here is the difference 1 //here is the difference 6
           [13] => AS1577 //here is the difference 7
           [PartNumber] => AS1577 //here is the difference 8
           [14] => ASSY7.60-15 8PLY W/WHL15X6 BLK //here is the difference 9
           [ItemDescription] => ASSY7.60-15 8PLY W/WHL15X6 BLK )
```

//Array 2:

```
     Array ( 
            [0] => XXX001 
            [CustomerId] => XXX001 
            [1] => XXX Company Name.*
            [Customer_Bill_Name] => XXX Company Name.* 
            [2] => DHE [WhichShipVia] => DHE [3] =>
            [INV_POSOOrderNumber] =>   [4] => 2014-12-19 
            [ShipByDate] => 2014-12-19  [5] => 
            [GoodThruDate] => [6] => 
            [CustomerSONo] => [7] => 15020 
            [Reference] => 15020 [8] => 2014-11-25 
            [TransactionDate] => 2014-11-25 [9] => 2 
            [DistNumber] => 2 
            [10] => 6.0000000000000000000 //here is the difference 1
            [Quantity] => 6.0000000000000000000 //here is the difference 2
            [11] => 600274  //here is the difference 3
            [ItemId] => 600274 //here is the difference 4
            [12] => ASSY9.5L-15SL/8 FLT I1 15X8 6-6, BLK (GWT-951508)(16)      
            [SalesDescription] => ASSY9.5L-15SL/8 FLT I1 15X8 6-6, BLK (GWT-951508)(16) //here is the difference 5
            [13] => AS1601 //here is the difference 6
            [PartNumber] => AS1601 //here is the difference 7
            [14] => ASSY9.5L-15 W/WHL15X8 6/6 BLK //here is the difference 8
            [ItemDescription] => ASSY9.5L-15 W/WHL15X8 6/6 BLK ) //here is the difference 9
```

Comment: if they're coming from a db and share a common field, why not just use a `JOIN`ed query in the first place?

Comment: can you give an example of output you're expecting?